# Websocket working in Postman, but not in Chrome

Tags: websocket

I am having a spring boot application, where I created some websockets.

I can connect to them on postman via `localhost:8080/ws/v1` , but when I try to connect to the websockt in chrome with the following code

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws/v1");
```

it is not working.

Do you have any idea if the browser has some extra security checks like CORS for http requests that I need to handle?

Comment: Did you ever find what happened? It's working perfectly through POSTMAN but not from the browser...

Comment: For me it works on localhost from Chrome. But on remote it woks only through Postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am suspecting the culprit might be not using a secure connection. (wss:// not ws://)
Have seen a bunch of posts saying chrome does not allow unsecured websockets.

Comment: It's better to post an answer _after_ you've confirmed it works, rather than posting your _suspicions_ moments before.